# Putting element with same symbol for changing value in legend with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a layer with forest districts and I need to generate map of every district. That is quite uncomplicated, however maps need to have a legend, where the symbology is the same for every district, but the name changes. Few solutions came to my mind, but they have certain disadvantages:

- creating layers for every district and updating symbology, but that seems too be overly complicating task
- I could put a text element on the legend and just update its content with name, but that is "not elegant" - eventual moving legend will mess up the layout
- I thought, as I use Definition Query anyway, I could use symbology type Single Symbol and just update description with district name, but I couldn`t find entry for this feature.

Here is a sample for second idea:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("districts", ["district_name", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor: 
    for row in cursor:
        for TextElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
            if TextElement.name == "forest_district":
                TextElement.text = row[0]
```

It would be best if I could treat single symbol description in a similar manner as `TextElement`, but as I said I couldn't find any entry for this.

So, I would like to know if anyone knows how to edit description in single symbol symbology type with Python? Or maybe someone has better idea for solving my task?

EDIT: I finally put `TextElement` next to symbol on legend and used the loop from example to assign district names. The good thing is that text can be changed even after grouping legend with `TextElement`, so there is no mess after moving legend. It looks good, nevertheless I am not very proud of this solution.

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: @PolyGeo how do you want me to show my code concerning this question? Should I show code for cases that are not suitable for me? I find my problem statement rather clear, however I am not able to provide code for something that I don`t even know if can be coded.

Comment: Yes - show code snippets that illustrate what you have tried and why they are unsuitable for you.  Q&As here are give and take,  The code you show may be useful to someone else.  Asking for code without giving some never seems like a good trade for anyone but the asker.  No need to show code for all three ideas you have; just show the one that gets closest to achieving what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok I added most significant in my opinion code part.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a mapbook with datadriven.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/building-map-books-with-arcgis.htm

But you dont have to create tiles, because you have you district boundary. After creation of mapbook you can display your district name under (insert/Dynamic text/datadriven page attribute). Than when export to PDF chose pages than "All Pages".

Comment: That is good idea, but not for my case. I need these maps in quite specific format, that I cannot change and also I need to export them in PNG.